# Python variable in string error

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm putting a variable in a print statement, and I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\workspace\First Python Project\com\fireboxtraining\Person.py", line 13, in <module>
    print("Dude, %s is not yes or no... come on.") % (game)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

This is my code:

```
    '''
Created on Apr 17, 2017

@author: Samuel
'''
game = input("Would you like to play a game? Please answer with \"Yes\" or \"No\".")
game = game.lower()
if game == "yes":
    print("Great! Let's play.")
elif game == "no":
    print("Ok, I guess we won't play.")
else: 
    print("Dude, %s is not yes or no... come on.") %(game)
```

I'm just learning python and I don't understand why this isn't working. Please help!

Comment: You need to handle the case when you don't input any answer. The value is blank or None so it does not make sense to print it.

Comment: the last line should be `print("Dude, %s is not yes or no... come on." %(game))`. Mind the `print` right parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple parentheses being off. You have:

```
print("Dude, %s is not yes or no... come on.") %(game)
```

it should be:

```
print("Dude, %s is not yes or no... come on." % (game) )
```